# What is the proper way to validate datatype of csv data in spark?

Tags: apache-spark

We have a JSON file as input to the spark program(which describe schema definition and constraints which we want to check on each column) and I want to perform some data quality checks such as (Not NULL, UNIQUE) and datatype validations as well(Wants to check whether csv file contains the data according to json schema or not?).

JSON File:

{

"id":"1",

"name":"employee",

"source":"local",

"file_type":"text",

"sub_file_type":"csv",

"delimeter":",",

"path":"/user/all/dqdata/data/emp.txt",

"columns":[

{"column_name":"empid","datatype":"integer","constraints":["not null","unique"],"values_permitted":["1","2"]},

{"column_name":"empname","datatype":"string","constraints":["not null","unique"],"values_permitted":["1","2"]},

{"column_name":"salary","datatype":"double","constraints":["not null","unique"],"values_permitted":["1","2"]},

{"column_name":"doj","datatype":"date","constraints":["not null","unique"],"values_permitted":["1","2"]},

{"column_name":"location","string":"number","constraints":["not null","unique"],"values_permitted":["1","2"]}

]

}

Sample CSV input :

empId,empname,salar,dob,location

1,a,10000,11-03-2019,pune

2,b,10020,14-03-2019,pune

3,a,10010,15-03-2019,pune

a,1,10010,15-03-2019,pune

Keep in mind that,

1) intentionally I have put the invalid data for empId and name field(check last record).
2) The number of column in the json file is not fixed?

Question:

How can I ensure that an input data file contains all the records as per the given datatype(in JSON) file or not?

We have tried below things:

1) If we try to load the data from the CSV file using a data frame by applying external schema, then the spark program immediately throws some cast exception(NumberFormatException, etc) and it abnormally terminates the program. But I want to continue the execution flow and log the specific error as "Datatype mismatch error for column empID".
Above scenario works only when we call some RDD action on data frame which I felt a weird way to validate schema.

Please guide me, How we can achieve it in spark?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a free lunch here you have to write this process yourself but the process you can do is...

1. Read the csv file as a `Dataset` of `Strings` so that every row is good
2. Parse the Dataset using the `map` function to check for `Null` or datatype problems per column
3. Add an extra two columns, a `boolean` called like `validRow` and a `String` called like `message` or `description`
4. With the parser mentioned in '2.', do some sort of `try/catch` or a `Try/Success/Failure` for each value in each column and catch the exception and set the `validRow` and the `description` column accordingly
5. Do a filter and write one `DataFrame/DataSet` that is successful (`validRow` flag is set to `True`) to a success place, and write the error `DataFrame/DataSet` to an error place

Comment: Thanks Mike.looking at  your 2 point i will have to use the columns metadata inside spark transformation(FYI. datatype/metadata is set to java object dynamicaly ) . so how can i access them inside spark transformation.so that i can perform datatype validation on each column.please send me a link of code if you know.

Comment: You can use the ordinal position of each column and validate against the same ordinal position of the schema. You can do this using a for loop or using the List/Cons pattern to iterate through the list of columns

Comment: Yes, I had tried same thing but problem is,Inside map i cannot access that prepoulated column metadata list because AFAIK,tranformations are executed on executors.

Comment: Yes they are but since you already pull it into a Dataset of strings, it is already on an executor

Comment: No, i am not pulling metadata into dataset it's just prepopulated into plain java object.

Comment: The metadata doesn’t need to be in a Dataset.  The metadata depending on how u do it is just an array of strings and there isn’t any reason why it wouldn’t be on the executor